# pytorch collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'to'

Tags: pytorch

this is my main code,but I don't know how to fix the problem?

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = torch.load('./checkpoints/fcn_model_5.pth')  # 加载模型
model = model.to(device)
```

Comment: You are loading the checkpoint as a state_dict, it is not a `nn.module` object.

Answer (score 4):

You are loading the checkpoint as a state dict, it is not a nn.module object.

```py
checkpoint = './checkpoints/fcn_model_5.pth'

model = your_model() # a torch.nn.Module object
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(checkpoint ))
model = model.to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is simply you are loading your model as a dict, instead of `nn.Module`. Here is an another approach you can employ without converting to `nn.Module` bloat [adopted from here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-get-a-cpu-state-dict/24712/2):

```
for k, v in model.items():
  model[k] = v.to(device)
```

Now, you have an ordered dict with the items at correct place.

Please note that you will still have an ordered dict instead of `nn.Module`. You will not be able to forward pass anything from an ordered dict.